# What is the best method to combine (aggregate) multiple Excel files?

Tags: excel

I have multiple EXCEL spreadsheets that contain the SAME columns, just different data per source.

---

**EXCEL File #1:**

URL                     |     HITS

http://myothersite.com        5

http://mysite.com             8

**EXCEL File #2:**

URL                     |     HITS

http://mysite.com             2

**EXCEL File COMBINED**:

URL                     |     HITS
http://mysite.com            **10**

http://myothersite.com        5

---

I need a solution that will **AGGREGATE all of the data from the individual spreadsheets into ONE combined spreadsheet**.  Each spreadsheet will have the same columns, just different data.  Hopefully this is a common problem with some standard solutions.  I'm open to programmatic solution as well as software solutions.  Thanks!

jg

Comment: Voted to migrate to Super User given accepted answer is an addin, not code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use the addin [RDBMerge](http://www.rondebruin.nl/merge.htm).

Comment: This worked great.  To add to it.  Use RDBMerge, then use the Excel "consolidate" feature to Sum up duplicate rows -- and merge duplicates.  Thanks!