# combining two excel sheets into one by using few columns as key

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a excel worksheet combining problem and I am a COMPLETELY NOOB on VBA.

So the worksheet to be added may have different number of columns(headings) but the key ones I am gonna use is city, street name, and street number aka address.

If the to be added has a new address, add the entire row to the existing.

If the to be added has an existing address, check if there's non existing column for that row, if yes add that column to existing.

Number of columns and rows of two sheets could be different but they all will have at least the address columns.

Can anyone tell me how to do this with a Macro? Or should i dig in some other method?

Thanks in advance.

```
    Sub combine()
    Dim inName, inNum, inCity As String
    Dim IncNum As Integer
    Dim temp As Range
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim counter As Integer


For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells

If cell <> "" And cell.Row <> 1 Then
    inCity = cell.Value
    inName = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell.Row, 2)
    inNum = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell.Row, 3)

    Set temp = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Find(what:=inCity)

    If temp Is Nothing Then
    'find the last row of the existing sheet
        lrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        IncNum = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Count
        For counter = 1 To IncNum
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrow + 1, counter).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lrow + 1, counter).Value
        Next counter

    End If

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried to fix the problem?

Comment: [**What is the best method to combine (aggregate) multiple Excel files?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886366/what-is-the-best-method-to-combine-aggregate-multiple-excel-files/15886432#15886432)

Comment: I didn't code from scratch since i have zero experience if that is what you are asking but I did a lot of research on the topic and hoping to get a good start and work on it from then on.

Comment: @Santosh I am trying to program myself not using any kinda of add-in.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Here is the tag that I forgot.

Comment: I modified my question it seems like the code Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrow + 1, counter).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lrow + 1, counter).Value is not doing the adding properly, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify you problem a bit.
Are you looking to add just the three columns (city,street name, street number) to your existing worksheet?

If so, what you need to do is identify the column numbers that corresponds to your three input columns in the input sheet. 
Then you write a loop looping through all cells in these column.
In each loop you will try to find the values in your existing sheet.
If not found append to the end of your existing sheet.
If found, check each of the three columns for a blank cell and overwrite the value.

Lets say street name is the cell that will always have a value in your existing sheet.
existing sheet (street name = column 1, street number = column 2, city = column 3)
input sheet (street name = column 30, street number = column 31, city = column 1)
the code will look similar to :

```
Sub update()
Dim inName, inNum, inCity As String
Dim x As Range
Dim temp As Range
Dim lrow As Long

'loop through each cell in column 30 containing street name
For Each cell In Sheets("INPUT").UsedRange.Columns(30).Cells
    'so you dont look for blanks and skips the header row
    If cell <> "" And cell.Row <> 1 Then
        inName = cell.Value
        inNum = Sheets("INPUT").Cells(cell.Row, 31).Value
        inCity = Sheets("INPUT").Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value

        Set temp = Sheets("EXISTING").Columns(1).Find(what:=cell.Value)
        If temp Is Nothing Then
            'means its not found
            'find the last row in the existing sheet
            lrow = Sheets("EXISTING").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            With Sheets("Existing")
                .Cells(lrow + 1, 1) = inName
                .Cells(lrow + 1, 2) = inNum
                .Cells(lrow + 1, 3) = inCity
            End With
        Else
            'means its found
            'override existing values with new ones add if = "" for each one if you dont want to overwrite
            With Sheets("Existing")
                    .Cells(temp.Row, 1) = inName
                    .Cells(temp.Row, 2) = inNum
                    .Cells(temp.Row, 3) = inCity
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So for each row I am adding every column of it if it contains a not existing address, if it contains an existing address i am only adding the columns thats missing. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Here is the tag that I forgot. @DerekCheng

Comment: Which column would you use to check if it is an existing address? do you have a concatenated column? or is one of the columns more important than the other? @user2600411

Comment: The code i just posted is trying to add the row that is not existed in the existing sheet by not existed it means it does not have the address in the input sheet(address = city + street name + street #). Any idea why it is not working? @DerekCheng

Comment: @user2600411 
Okay now I see your problem. I have a few more questions for you before I update the code
1. Do you have a set of column headers in sheet1 that identifies city, street name and street #?
2. Do you need a perfect match of the address to count it as existing

Comment: Yes and Yes @DerekCheng